# What should the statements be if a character has been entered in a textbox in C#?

Tags: c#, button, if-statement, label

Question 1:

As the code states, if spaces are entered in the textbox then the button remains disabled, but if a character or string of characters has been entered when what should be wrote to enable the button? I think there should be an if statement but I don't know the statement.

```
MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
UTF8Encoding utf81 = new UTF8Encoding();
textBox1.Text = BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(utf81.GetBytes(textBox30.Text)))

SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
UTF8Encoding utf82 = new UTF8Encoding();
textBox2.Text = BitConverter.ToString(sha1.ComputeHash(utf82.GetBytes(textBox30.Text)))

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox30.Text))
{
btnHash3.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
btnHash3.Enabled = true;
}
```

Question 2

Also on a slightly different note, how do I enable a button once two files are read in from two filestreams and displayed inside two labels?

```
{
System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 sha1 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();


FileStream file1 = new FileStream(lblBrowse1.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
FileStream file2 = new FileStream(lblBrowse2.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);


                byte[] hash1 = md5.ComputeHash(file1);
                byte[] hash2 = md5.ComputeHash(file2);

                file1.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                file2.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                byte[] hash3 = sha1.ComputeHash(file1);
                byte[] hash4 = sha1.ComputeHash(file2);

                file1.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                file2.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                file1.Close();
                file2.Close();

                textBox1.Text = BitConverter.ToString(hash1).Replace("-", "");
                textBox2.Text = BitConverter.ToString(hash2).Replace("-", "");
                textBox6.Text = BitConverter.ToString(hash3).Replace("-", "");
                textBox7.Text = BitConverter.ToString(hash4).Replace("-", "")

                if (textBox1.Text == textBox2.Text
                 && textBox6.Text == textBox7.Text)

                {
                    MessageBox.Show("These two files are identical.");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("These two files are different.");
                }
            }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `if (textbox does not contain what you want) { do nothing }`

Comment: What is this code in? keypress event?

Comment: C#. Sorry, I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question, use .Contains to check for spaces:

```
bthHash3.Enabled = !myString.Contains(" ");
```

Since you are just setting a boolean, I collapsed the if into one line. To answer your second, it slightly depends on if you are in a multi-threaded environment. Of course, you could always write the following:

```
ReadMyFile(file1);
ReadMyFile(file2);
myButton.Enabled = true;
```

Which works since ReadMyFile should block while reading, so the enabled line won't be hit until all the reads are complete. If you are threaded, then do this:

```
int completeCount = 0;

void ThreadedRead()
{
    //Read file synchronously
    completedCount++;
    CheckReadCompletion();
}

void CheckReadCompletion()
{
   if (completedCount == 2)
      myButton.Enabled = true;
}
```

You would start "ThreadedRead" for each file you need to read. Please let me know if I can clarify anything!

You wouldn't need to do this in the above scenario (because you are just setting the enabled flag) but with complex enough behavior, make sure to put a lock around `completedCount` and the call to CheckReadCompletion. You could modify it to this:

```
int completeCount = 0;
object completionLock = new object();

void ThreadedRead()
{
    //Read file synchronously

    lock (completionLock)
    {
       completedCount++;
       CheckReadCompletion();
    }
}

void CheckReadCompletion()
{
   if (completedCount == 2)
      myButton.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make the button enabled if the textbox contains anything that is not a space, it makes it enabled if the textbox contains any space.

Comment: Daniel, I tried this but it didn't work. I'm not a great programmer so could you please tell me where I'm going wrong? I've amended the code so it's clearer to understand.

Comment: The first line replaces the `if string.IsNull....` block (and associated else. `myButton.Enabled = true` goes after you close both files in the other code block. Other than that, I'll need code that actually uses what I posted and a better explanation of what "didn't work" before I can assist much further.

Comment: I replaced the if statement with your line of code (replacing the variable names so there are no errors of course) and it runs but for some reason, it has no effect. I set its ReadOnly property to "False" so its disabled at first but it stays like that. As for the second piece of code, it doesn't like "ReadMyFile". I've tried changing the name into something that is referenced but nothing will be accepted. By the way, apologies for the name Daniel. It's been a long day.

Comment: You can ignore "ReadMyFile" :). It was just a placeholder function that would (if it existed) synchronously read a file. Your existing code already does that, so just put the set for "Enabled" after you close the files. For the disabled, make sure the code is actually getting called when you change the text. Is it in an event handler like TextChanged?

Comment: No, it just sits on its own. Re: the other code, that doesn't work either. It's not a big issue though. I'm sure I'll figure it out. Although I couldn't get it work, I'll vote for this answer as I'm sure I'm doing something wrong on my end. Thank for your help and time Bradley!

Comment: Well, if its not in an event handler, its probably not running and so not setting your enable/disable correctly :). Let me know if you have any more questions, I hope you are able to successfully integrate my solution!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need an `if` statement, you can just use the result of a condition as the value for the `Enabled` property. Trim the string and check if the length is greater than zero to find out if it has any non-space characters:

```
btnHash3.Enabled = textBox30.Text.Trim().Length > 0;
```

To wait for two results before enabling a button, first create a counter, for example:

```
int fileCounter = 0;
```

After the code that adds the file content to a label, increase the counter and set the button status:

```
fileCounter++;
someButton.Enabled = fileCounter == 2;
```

Comment: Text.Trim() won't fail if there is a space in the middle.

Comment: Guffa, I also tried this but it didn't work. As mentioned to Bradley, I've amended the code so it's clearer to understand. Could you please tell what goes where.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Yes. The length will be non-zero if there is anything other than just spaces in the string.

Comment: @user3577207: What do you mean when you say that it didn't work? Can you be more specific?